# How to convert a UTC datetime string into users' current timezone?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, npm

I am using laravel 5.7 for api and vue for front end. In api response I am getting a user's last seen timestamp as `last_seen: "2019-04-17 05:20:37"` which is by default in UTC format.

**Laravel API code:**

```
$user_details = array(
            'user_id' => $userId,
            'name' => $userDetails->name,
            'email' => $userDetails->email,
            'phone' => $userDetails->contact,
            'account_creation_date' => $userDetails->created_at->toDateTimeString(),
            'last_seen' => $lastSeen != null ? $lastSeen->toDateTimeString() : $userDetails->last_login->toDateTimeString(),
            'language' => 'English',
            'country' => $country->name
        );

$user_profile['user_details'] = $user_details;
return response()->api(true, 'Success', $user_profile);
```

**This the api response I am getting:**
[image]

On the front end i.e in vue I am using [Dayjs Package](https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs) to show user's last seen as `[Day|Hours|Minutes] ago` but the problem is **intended user has logged in just now** but I am getting it is showing `6 Hours ago`

Since I am in *Asia/Kolkata* timezone the code is taking 5.5/6 hours also in consideration.

Also I tried with `moment.js` but I get `undefined function moment.tz.guess()` error

**This is what I have tried so far:**

I am passing the datetime string to my vuejs function:

```
import dayjs from "dayjs";

convertFromNow(date) {
 return dayjs(date).fromNow();
},
```

and then call this method to print as `1 minute ago`.

```
<div class="side-box mt-4">
                  <h2 class="side-head">
                    <i class="fa fa-clock-o" />
                    {{ convertFromNow(userInfo.user_details.last_seen) }}
                    <h6 class="text-gray">
                      Last seen
                    </h6>
                  </h2>
                </div>
```

Expected results I need is I should get user's last seen as per my timezone no matter what is UTC time.

Comment: What is the problem in using moment.js? It is a great library.

Comment: @iwaduarte there is no problem in using `moment.js` but I am getting error in guessing user's timezone.

Comment: Also refer to this link to understand what is happening with your code.
https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/issues/523 .

Could you please also edit your question to include the code you are using with moment.js ?

Comment: Why is your API returning date/time strings without timezone information? IMHO, the best transport format for dates is ISO 8601, ie `2019-04-17T05:20:37Z`. This makes it unambiguous and JS can parse it correctly. In my browser, parsing your `"2019-04-17 05:20:37"` string treats it as local time (which seems to be your problem)

Comment: You can get user's current time using `toLocaleString()`

Comment: From the [dayjs documentation](https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs/blob/dev/docs/en/API-reference.md): _"If you want to parse or display in UTC, you can use `.utc` `.local` `.isUTC` with plugin UTC"_

Comment: The real question is how are your timestamps stored and what PHP code are you using to set them in the API response? Fix that to use ISO 8601 format and all your problems will probably disappear

Comment: @Phil By default laravel stores timestamps into UTC format.

Comment: 1) That doesn't answer my question at all, and 2) `2019-04-17 05:20:37` is **not** a _"UTC format"_. How are you crafting the API response? What **exactly** is the stored data format? If it's in a DB, what data-type is the column?

Comment: @Phil I added the Laravel API code and updated the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also try to use `moment.js`, you need to tell `moment` time is in UTC

```js
console.log(moment.utc("2019-04-17 05:20:37").fromNow())
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: This answer works-around the problem. You should aim to fix it at the source

Comment: @Phil Yes it worked and I implemented this according to the vue.

`import moment from "moment";`

`convertFromNow(date) {`
`return moment.utc(date).fromNow();`
` },`

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution in Vanilla JavaScript (without depending on external libraries such as moment.js or days.js).

The trick is to append 'UTC' to your date string, before converting it to a JavaScript [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object.

```js
const dateString = '2019-04-17 05:20:37';
const localDate = new Date(`${dateString} UTC`);
console.log(localDate)
```

If you run the above code on your local browser (Chrome) console, it should print the time based on your (or your users') local timezone.

Comment: _"If you run the above code on your local browser (Chrome) console, it should print the time based on your (or your users') local timezone."_ - And Firefox will print `null`

Comment: Thank you @wentjun your solution helped me :) but let me test in other browsers too.

Comment: @Andreas could you please let me know your firefox version? I believe that only applies to the 'older' Firefox browsers

Comment: @DineshSuthar I have to add a disclaimer, that method may not work on the older IE browsers.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of your question is that you need to get the user's timezone (through their browser). I will demonstrate this using moment's cdn.

You need to have both `moment.js` and `moment-timezone-with-data.js`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.23/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
```

Then using this function: `moment.tz.guess();` in your code should give you the user's timezone.

After this, you can pass the timezone you get to *your API* to retrieve the correct time for this timezone.

As a plus, if you're using Carbon you (might) need to use `setTimezone()`:

```
Carbon::parse($time)->setTimezone($tz);
```

> Others see: https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/guessing-user-timezone/

Answer (score 1):

Your date/time string *"2019-04-17 05:20:37"* may represent a UTC time but JavaScript will parse it as a local time, meaning the times will **always** be wrong.

The very simple answer is to use an unambiguous format like ISO 8601 / Atom, eg

```
"2019-04-17T05:20:37+00:00"
```

Carbon provides an easy method that you can drop-in as a replacement for `toDateTimeString()`

```php
$user_details = [
    // snip
    'account_creation_date' => $userDetails->created_at->toAtomString(),
    'last_seen' => $lastSeen != null ? $lastSeen->toAtomString() : $userDetails->last_login->toAtomString(),
    // snip
];
```

See https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-commonformats

Comment: Thanks @Phil for pointing out this improvement. Actually I didn't know about this `toAtomString()` method of Carbon.